# Does "Anonymous Recursion" work in .NET? It does in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, y-combinator, anonymous-recursion

I surfed into [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx) site a few days ago on "Anonymous Recursion in C#". The thrust of the article is that the following code will not work in C#:

```
Func<int, int> fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
```

The article then goes into some detail about how to use [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) and the [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator) to get back to "Anonymous Recursion" in C#. This is pretty interesting but a tad complex for my everyday coding I am afraid. At this point at least...

I like to see stuff for myself so I opened the Mono [CSharp REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) and entered that line. No errors. So, I entered `fib(8);`. Much to my great surprise, it worked! The REPL replied back with `21`!

I thought maybe this was some magic with the REPL, so I fired-up 'vi', typed in the following program, and compiled it.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = int.Parse(args[0]);
        Func<int, int> fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
        Console.WriteLine(fib(x));
    }
}
```

It built and ran perfectly too!

I am running Mono 2.10 on a Mac. I do not have access to a Windows machine right now so I cannot test this on .NET on Windows.

Has this been fixed on .NET as well or is this a silent feature of Mono? The article is a couple of years old.

If it is Mono only, I cannot wait for the next job interview where they ask me to write a Fibinocci function in the language of my choice (Mono C#) where I have to provide the caveat that .NET will not work. Well, actually I can wait since I love my job. Still, interesting...

**Update:**

Mono is not really doing "anonymous" recursion as it is using `fib` as a named delegate. My bad. The fact that the Mono C# compiler assumes a `null` value for `fib` before assignment is a bug as noted below. I say "compiler" because the .NET CLR would run the resulting assembly just fine even though the .NET C# compiler would not compile the code.

For all the interview Nazis out there:

```
Func<int, int> fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
```

can be replaced with an iterative version:

```
Func<int, int> fib = n => 
{
    int old = 1;
    int current = 1;
    int next;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        next = current + old;
        old = current;
        current = next;
    }
    return current;
};
```

You might want to do this because the recursive version is inefficient in a language like C#. Some might suggest using [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) but, since this is still slower than the iterative method, they may just be being wankers. :-)

At this point though, this becomes more of an ad for functional programming than anything else (since the recursive version is so much nicer). It really does not have anything to do with my original question, but some of the answers thought that it was important.

Comment: If any job interviewer asked me that I'd walk out.

Comment: Last I checked you still have to declare the `Func` on a separate line, I'd be happy to be incorrect!

Comment: Thanks Jonathon! I spell badly in the morning. :-)

Comment: As you can see from the answers, you don't want to do that in an interview. Besides this being the "stupid" implementation of the Fibonacci function, it is not even valid C# code.

Comment: @Martinho. See my comment to Eric about the interview question. Thank you for the advice but I was not being serious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=317420) in the Mono compiler. It violates section §12.3.3 of the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf). The variable *fib* cannot be used in the variable initializer, because it isn't definitely assigned.

Comment: Opened over 6 years ago... good to see that bugs get fixed in open source much "faster" than in closed source software ;)

Comment: @Matthew - There are probably bugs from day one in any software that last until the last user finally turns it off. I could not help but respond to your quip though...at least this bug has not been around 17 years: http://techchunks.com/technology/microsoft-to-patch-17-year-old-computer-bug/

Comment: Discovered in 2010... that's 1 month

Answer (score 7):

As I noted in a comment above, if Mono does that then they have a bug. The spec is clear that this is supposed to be detected as an error. The bug is of course mostly harmless, and most of the time does what you want. We've considered changing the rules to make this sort of recursion legal; basically we'd have to add a special case to the spec that says that this narrowly-defined case is legal.  It's never been a high enough priority though.

For more thoughts on this issue see my article on the subject:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/706398.aspx

And by the way, I would not hire anyone who gave me a straight-up recursive implementation of fib in an interview. It is *extremely* inefficient; its running time is proportional to the size of its output, and fib grows exponentially.  To make it efficient use recursion *with memoization*, or implement the obvious iterative solution.

Comment: Clearly the interview crack was meant to be a joke though. I expected somebody to make the throwaway comment about efficiency but I am surprised to hear it from you here. After all, your comment on the blog I took it from was "Awesome Wes.  This is one of the most clear explanations of the y combinator I've seen yet." Perhaps I should quip back that I would never hire a compiler dev that cannot implement tail call elimination. :-) Smile, it's early (for me at least).

Comment: @Justin: point taken. However, to be fair, Wes's article was not intended to give an efficient implementation of fib, it was intended to be a tutorial on the Y combinator.

Comment: agreed. Also to be fair, my implementation was a consequence of Wes's implementation. No? For further humor, Scott Hanselman calls this exact code snippet ["a great use of C# 3.0"](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode13FibonacciEdition.aspx). From my vantage, Scott seems to have been a pretty nice hire for Microsoft. Perhaps you need broaden your interviewing horizons. :-)  By the way, despite my tone, I mean no disrespect. You are clearly leagues smarter than me and you contribute greatly to a product that I love. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I'm surprised you have such low standards.  I thought for sure you'd require an interviewee to come up with an _O(log n)_ solution (e.g via matrix exponentiation), if not the _O(1)_ closed form solution! [:-)]

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
Func<int, int> fib = null;
fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
```

... The problem is that fib isn't defined when you try to use it in the above method so the static analyzer reports a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I get that. In fact, they give this example in the article.

Comment: This is almost certainly what REPL is turning your inline assignment into. Basically VS chokes on the evaluation of the lambda; "fib" technically doesn't exist yet when creating the lambda that will be assigned to fib. Your Mono compiler's just smart enough to take a step back and see the larger statement.

Comment: @KeithS this isn't a "smart enough" thing in mono... it's a bug from the spec.  See Eric Lippert's response (he should know... he's on the Microsoft C# team.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, in my excitement, I was fundamentally mistaken. Neither .NET nor Mono provides "Anonymous Recursion" in the way that the original article means. You could not pass around `fib` as a self-contained entity.

Check out the following sequence in the Mono C# REPL:

```
csharp> Func<int, int> fib = n => n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n; 
csharp> fibCopy = fib;
csharp> fib(6);
8
csharp> fibCopy(6);
8
csharp> fib = n => n * 2;
csharp> fib(6);
12
csharp> fibCopy(6);
18
```

This is because:

```
fib = n => n * 2;
fibCopy = n > 1 ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2) : n;
```

In other words,

```
fibCopy = n > 1 ? (n - 1) * 2 + (n - 2) * 2 : n;    // at the moment
```

Clearly, `fibCopy` is just pointing at the current definition of `fib` (the delegate) and not at itself. So Mono is really just pre-assigning a value of `null` to `fib` during the initial assignment so that the assignment is valid.

I much prefer the convenience of not having to declare `null` so I do like this behavior. Still, it is not really what the original article is talking about.

Comment: You're right. It's not quite "anonymous recursion" because you're using the "named" *fib* function.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft's C# compiler, it will only work if you first set `fib` to `null`.

Otherwise, it will give an error because `fib` is used before it's assigned.
Mono's compiler is "smart" enough to avoid this error (in other words, it violates the official spec)

Comment: By smart enough, you mean smarter than the spec, right? Some might call that a bug.

Comment: Which compiler is "smarter" is debatable.  Different decisions were made in their designs.

Comment: For completeness, the violation of the spec regards section §12.3.3. The variable fib is not definitely assigned because it isn't *before* the statement, and it only becomes definitely assigned *after* the statement.

Comment: @Martinho is correct; if Mono does that, technically they have a bug; the spec says that this should be illegal. A mostly harmless bug, of course. It would be interesting to see if the Mono compiler allows delegate D D(D d); /*...*/ D d = ((D)(c=>c(d))(e=>e); because there the value of d actually *is* used before it is initialized. If Mono allows that then the bug can actually be used to observe an uninitialized local variable.

Comment: Actually, this bug is already kind of reported: it's mentioned by Miguel in the comments of bug [#317420](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=317420).

Comment: I actually don't like the wording @SLaks used.  It appears to favor mono, which I don't think is correct.  -1.