# Is it valid for a lambda to, essentially, close over itself?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Is this lambda recursion valid?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::function<int(int)> g = [&g](int k) {
       return (k ? k * g(k-1) : 1);
   };

   std::cout << g(10); // 3628800
}
```

It [appears to compile and run ok](http://www.ideone.com/iFCKf), but I'm nervous about closing over `g` in the same statement that I initialise it. Strict validity on a scale of 1-10...?

Comment: In C#, that wouldn't compile; you'd need to break it into two statements.

Comment: C++0x examples [here](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/c-recursive-lambda-functions/) break it into 2 statements, but never explains why.

Comment: I think it's undefined behaviour. Lambdas aren't designed to recursion cause it's a anonymous function, am I right?

Comment: @Hauleth: I have a name for it (`g`), but I don't know when the reference is formed and thus whether it's bound to a valid `std::function` object.

Comment: Well `g` has been declared before the initialiser, and I'm pretty sure it's valid to take a reference to a declared but uninitialised object, in which case this is fine. I'll see if I can find some Standardese to back that up.

Comment: Yeah, I know you named it, but I'm asking for general purposes. IMHO it's kind of weird way to use lambdas cause `g` is empty while U are trying to use it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's my gut feeling too, but I'm finding it completely unspecified. Actually, I can't find: (a) when the closure is formed, _or_ (b) rules about references here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189096/standard-reference-for-int-foo-foo is similar but we need a new question about `int foo(int& y) { return 0; } int x = foo(x);` I think, to serve as a basis for this question! Unless we can prove that lambdas do late binding and thus it'd be irrelevant..

Comment: @SLaks: It would also not compile in java, where is the point?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: AFAIK, the Java equivalent (final variable with local inner class) would compile.

Comment: @SLaks: So would the C# equivalent (that is, two statements). So where is the point in that C++ code does not compile as C#? How does it provide any insight into the issue?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: He's just making a side comment for comparison; where in C++ I had to ask this question, in C# the syntax prohibits the issue coming up. It's interesting.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: In Java, I don't think you need two statements.  In C++, you do not need two statements.  In C#, you do.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488015/does-anonymous-recursion-work-in-net-it-does-in-mono

Comment: If that wasn't allowed, we might try to pass the lambda to itself as a parameter. Any ideas how to make this work: `auto fact = [](??? g, int k) {
       return (k ? k * g(k-1) : 1);
   };` What's the type of g? Then we'd call it with `fact(fact,5)` to get the factorial of 5. Is there any hope?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: You're trying to invent the [Y Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator).  Functional programming is lots of fun.

Comment: @SLaks. Indeed. I'd have mentioned that if comments allowed more space :-) I program mostly in C++ and a little in Haskell. I'm hoping to use more Haskell-type ideas in due course in my C++. I think C++ needs a garbage collector before I can start porting all the Haskell libraries into C++ !

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Just use C#; it's the best of both worlds.  Or F#.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid : See [Boost.Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/libs/phoenix/) if you're not familiar with it already.

Comment: @SLaks, I've considered that many times (including F#) over the years. But I'm a Linux user. I'm aware of Mono and so on, but I'm not quite ready to make the leap from the comfort of g++ (and ghc for Haskell)

Comment: @ildjarn , Phoenix is back onto my todo list (again). After the holidays maybe!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the point at which you capture `g` by reference, it has been declared, so the name is available for use:

> 3.3.2/1 The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer

You are allowed to use objects in limited ways before they are initialised - basically, anything that doesn't depend on the value is OK:

> 3.8/6 before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy
>   has been allocated [...] any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited
>   ways. [...] using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined.

So by my understanding, what you are doing is well-defined.

(Although, being ultrapedantic, I don't think it's specified when the storage for an automatic object is allocated, and 8.3.2/5 says that "a reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object" without defining "valid", so there's scope to argue that it's not well-defined).

Comment: I'd agree that binding a reference shouldn't necessitate an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, but the language's semantics in this area are _very_ hard to interpret. :( Even for C++!

Comment: OK, I think this satisfies me!

Comment: I was just about to post this :P  Like any function definition, the code isn't executed right then; `g` does not need a value for the same reason `k` does not need a value, from the perspective of the definition.  `g` is being used with `[&g]`, but that's only taking the address of the future function.  And `g` exists at that point because the declarations happens before the assignment.

Comment: @user112358132134: Forming a pointer is not identical to binding a reference, the object is under construction and thus has some potentially complex semantics, and the point at which the lambda contents are executed is not relevant. And there's no assignment here.

Comment: @user112358132134 Although by intuition you might be correct, you might also see that we are moving in strict language lawyer territory here, where a reference doesn't need to be implemented like pointer and where practically working UB is still UB.

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that this would not be legal if (as is usually recommended for lambdas) you declare the type of `fact` as `auto`: an `auto` variable cannot be used in its own initializer.

Comment: @ChristopherNeylan: yes, as you said, it works _because_ it is a std::function; if std::function is replaced with auto (making g a 'pure' lambda) it will fail